# Display number of town visited for each driver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm actually trying to have a number of time that a driver visited a town.
I'm close to have the good result, but I need a little bit help to achieve this.

So here it is my database

```
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE
______________________________________
camion      immatriculation  char           <--- PK
camion      annee            date
camion      kilometrage      float
_____________________________________
conducteur  id_conducteur   int            <--- PK
conducteur  nom             varchar
conducteur  date_embauche   date
_______________________________________
trajet      id_conducteur   int            <--- PK, FK REFERENCES conducteur(id_conducteur)
trajet      immatriculation char           <--- PK, FK REFERENCES camion(immatriculation)
trajet      date_trajet     datetime       <--- PK
trajet      ville_depart    int            <--- FK REFERENCES ville(id)
trajet      ville_arrivee   int            <--- FK REFERENCES ville(id)
______________________________________
ville       id              int            <--- PK
ville       libelle         varchar
```

Then I want to know by example how many time a driver is gone to every town that he visited

So I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT c.nom, vd.libelle, COUNT(t.ville_depart) AS 'nbr_ville'
        FROM trajet t
        JOIN conducteur c ON c.id_conducteur = t.id_conducteur
        JOIN ville vd ON vd.id = t.ville_depart
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
        (
            (vd.libelle,vd.id,c.nom)
        )
    ) AS depart
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT c.nom, va.libelle, COUNT(t.ville_arrivee) AS 'nbr_ville'
        FROM trajet t
        JOIN conducteur c ON c.id_conducteur = t.id_conducteur
        JOIN ville va ON va.id = t.ville_arrivee
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
        (
            (va.libelle,va.id,c.nom)
        )
    ) AS arrivee
) AS touteville
ORDER BY touteville.nom,touteville.libelle
;
```

(I use grouping sets only for learning to use it, but I know that is could be replace by a simple 'group by')

So here it is what I have as a result:

```
nom     libelle     nbr_ville
BERNARD Avignon     2
BERNARD Avignon     1
BERNARD Bordeaux    1
BERNARD Bordeaux    1
BERNARD Nancy       3
BERNARD Nancy       3
BERNARD Paris       1
BERNARD Paris       1
BERNARD Strasbourg  1
DUPONT  Bordeaux    1
DUPONT  Bordeaux    1
DUPONT  Paris       1
DUPONT  Paris       1
DUPONT  Strasbourg  1
DUPONT  Strasbourg  1
MAXIME  Lyon        1
MAXIME  Lyon        1
MAXIME  Paris       1
MAXIME  Paris       1
MAXIME  Strasbourg  1
MAXIME  Toulouse    1
THIERY  Avignon     1
THIERY  Avignon     2
THIERY  Bordeaux    1
THIERY  Marseille   1
THIERY  Marseille   1
THIERY  Nancy       1
THIERY  Nancy       1
THIERY  Paris       2
THIERY  Paris       1
THIERY  Strasbourg  1
```

But I wish I could have **group** all the result by the column named 'libelle   ' which are the name of the town.

How could I do that?

I try to just do a GROUP BY libelle on the 'touteville' virtual table, but if I want to do that I have to add 'nbr_ville' and 'nom' to the group by or add it into a aggregate function, as SQL Server told me.

So what I want to have is:

```
nom     libelle     nbr_ville
BERNARD Avignon     3
BERNARD Bordeaux    2
BERNARD Nancy       6
```

Instead of

```
nom     libelle  nbr_ville
BERNARD Avignon  2
BERNARD Avignon  1
BERNARD Bordeaux 1
BERNARD Bordeaux 1
BERNARD Nancy    3
BERNARD Nancy    3
```

Comment: instead of select * from.. you simply select nom,libelle , sum(nbr_ville) as nbr_ville and then add a group by nom,libelle before the order by statement

Comment: Can't you just wrap what you actually have into another select and then group by nom libelle and nbr_ville and sum your count?

Comment: What would really help is turning that semi-description of tables into something consumable. Namely create table statements. And sample data that represent the issue. Seems you could greatly simplify this by changing the where predicate to join on either ville_depart OR ville_arrivee. Instead of three queries it would become one.

Comment: Ok i have got the result i wanted by using the solution that Harry have proposed.
Thank you :)
But how may i have the same result in just one queries... I'm sorry i don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you could simplify your entire query to something like this.

```
SELECT c.nom
    , vd.libelle
    , COUNT(t.ville_depart) AS nbr_ville
FROM trajet t
JOIN conducteur c ON c.id_conducteur = t.id_conducteur
JOIN ville vd ON vd.id = t.ville_depart 
             OR vd.id = t.ville_arrivee
group by c.nom
    , vd.libelle
order by c.nom
    , vd.libelle
```

Comment: Oh that's great ! I wasn't know i can do that... Sorry for this anoying question, i think i could have find it by myself with more research

Comment: Wasn't an annoying question at all. Glad this helped.